# Error en sentencia case SQL

Tags: sql

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy intentando que la sentencia SELECT me muestre el nombre de los personajes de un género en concreto, en este caso me es irrelevante.

El ejercicio consiste en utilizar la sentencia CASE, pero el programa no para de marcarme un error y por mucho que veo el vídeo explicativo no encuentro donde está.

El SELECT en concreto del que hablo es el último del código que adjunto:

```
CREATE TABLE marvels (
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   name TEXT,
   popularity INTEGER,
   alignment TEXT,
   gender TEXT, 
   height_m NUMERIC,
   weight_kg NUMERIC,
   hometown TEXT,
   intelligence INTEGER,
   strength INTEGER,
   speed INTEGER,
   durability INTEGER,
   energy_Projection INTEGER,
   fighting_Skills INTEGER);

INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(1, "Spider Man", 1, "Good", "Male", 1.78, 75.75, "USA", 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4);   
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(2, "Iron Man", 20, "Neutral", "Male", 1.98, 102.58, "USA", 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4); 
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(3, "Hulk", 18, "Neutral", "Male", 2.44, 635.29, "USA", 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(4, "Wolverine", 3, "Good", "Male", 1.6, 88.46, "Canada", 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 7);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(5, "Thor", 5, "Good", "Male", 1.98, 290.3, "Norway", 2, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(6, "Green Goblin", 91, "Bad", "Male", 1.93, 174.63, "USA", 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(7, "Magneto", 11, "Neutral", "Male", 1.88, 86.18, "Germany", 6, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4); INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(8, "Thanos", 47, "Bad", "Male", 2.01, 446.79, "Titan", 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(9, "Loki", 32, "Bad", "Male", 1.93, 238.14, "Jotunheim", 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 3);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(10, "Doctor Doom", 19, "Bad", "Male", 2.01, 188.24, "Latveria", 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4); 
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(11, "Jean Greay", 8, "Good", "Female", 1.68, 52.16, "USA", 3, 2, 7, 7, 7, 4);
INSERT INTO marvels VALUES(12, "Rogue", 4, "Good", "Female", 1.73, 54.43, "USA", 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7);

SELECT name AS Nombre, MAX(height_m) AS Máxima_Altura from marvels;
SELECT name AS Nombre, MIN(height_m) As Mínima_Altura from marvels;
SELECT AVG(height_m) As Estatura_Media from marvels;

SELECT name AS Nombre, AVG(height_m) AS Mediaaltura FROM marvels
GROUP BY height_m
HAVING height_m > 1.7 AND popularity<40;

SELECT name 
CASE 
WHEN gender="female" from marvels;
```

¿Alguien me echa una mano por favor?

Comment: Has probado CASE gender LIKE "female" ?

Comment: Efectivamente era esa la solución ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza:

```
CASE gender LIKE "female"
```

Así compararás la string y el campo `genero` de tu tabla.